# Распарсить XML с параметрами @params

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть `XML` получаемый со стороннего сервера:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["message_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["message_phone"]=>
    string(11) "**********"
    ["message_parts"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["message_zone"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["message_cost"]=>
    string(3) "0,6"
  }
}
```

Либо туплю, либо просто не понимаю, мне нужно вытащить значения **@attributes**

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);
```

Но как мне добраться до `$xml->@attributes`? Знак `@` не поставишь - нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);
$a = get_object_vars($xml);
var_dump($a["@attributes"]);
```

**UPDATE**

В случае с PHP 5.3 возможно и без костылей:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$a = (array)$xml;
var_dump($a["@attributes"]);
```

Comment: Молодца спс +1 тебе.

Comment: Тут просто очередная нелогичность в php, из массива в объект очень просто: `$obj = (object)$array;`, а вот обратно... `$arr = (array)$obj`, хотя странно, на 5.3 работает, раньше были проблемы

Comment: Вот то-то и оно!
Но мне благо не нужно их обратно впихивать, мне именно разобрать и INSERT в БД а там уже дело скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, работайте как с массивом: $xml['message_cost'] вернет "0,6".

Comment: Я сюда поместил только часть массива XML он огромен :) это вроде как 5я вложенность в него :) т.е. есть разделы в XML подразделы и т.д. и только там параметры к разделам, вот как оно загнуто :)

Comment: Не вопрос: я когда-то разбирал html подобным образом. Там получалось что-то типа `$table->tbody->tr[$i]->td[$j]->input[0]['value']`. =)

Comment: Все ответы учтены ;)  во, была такая тема около полутора лет назад.